# Fechar Janela de Download

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Como faço para fechar uma janela de download com o `jQuery` no `Internet Explorer`?

**Exemplo:**

```
<?php 

    $arquivo = $_GET["arquivo"];    
    header("Location: $arquivo");

   echo "<script>
            $(window).ready(function() {
               window.close();
            });

        </script>";
?>
```

---

**O link:**

```
<script> 
     function winOpen() {
          window.open("download2.php?torrent=$row[torrent]&id=$row[id]&user=$_SESSION[logininput]"
,null, "height=70,width=470,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no");
} 
</script>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="winOpen()">TORRENT</a>
```

O código acima funciona no `Firefox`, mas não no `IE`, lembrando que essa janela é uma popup de download de arquivo que é um torrent que vai abrir.

Comment: Se você está forçando o download de um torrent, para que precisa de um popup?

Comment: é um sistema do mesmo estilo do superdownloads, abre a popup com o download do torrent quando clica no link...

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu sei só se fecha janela popup com js, caso você tenha aberto ela com js. No caso se você usou a função window.open, deveria funcionar o window.close.

Answer (score 0):

**Janela que chama o popup**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function winOpen() 
    {
        window.open("aberto.html",null, "height=70,width=470,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no");
    } 
</script>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="winOpen()">Abrir</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Janela Popup que será fechada com tempo determinado e function [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Aberto Janela</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.close();
    }, 3000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**No seu exemplo coloque assim:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
            window.close();
        }, 3000);
});
</script>
```

*Alterando para esse código a mesma fechará em 3 segundos após aberto*

```
Funcionou nos navegadores: IE, Firefox e Google Chrome
```

Comment: cara, não esta funcionando, qual será o problema ? no código q vc postou vc não usou o header location no php, será q é isso ? quando tiro o header funciona

Comment: cara o seu código ta errado, o header no caso ali ta redirecionando para o contéudo de arquivo, retire então, se sem ele ta funcionando e verifique seu sistema. O código implementado por mim ta funcionando são dois html pegue os dois e teste se vai entender!!! ok? se tiver dúvida pergunte